# Flutter- How to know AudioService is stopped?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I am working with [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) flutter package. I want to pop a player page if Audio Service stops. How to get the Audio Service stopped event? I didn't find any events to check if service is stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer update: Since v0.18, the service is effectively always running while the app is running, so there is no longer a need to check. The following answer is for v0.17 and earlier.)

`AudioService.running` will emit `true` when the service is running and `false` when it is not.

To listen to when it changes from `true` to `false`, you could try this:

```dart
// Cast runningStream from dynamic to the correct type.
final runningStream =
    AudioService.runningStream as ValueStream<bool>;
// Listen to stream pairwise and observe when it becomes false
runningStream.pairwise().listen((pair) {
  final wasRunning = pair.first;
  final isRunning = pair.last;
  if (wasRunning && !isRunning) {
    // take action
  }
});
```

If you instead want to listen to the `stopped` playback state, you need to ensure that your background audio task actually emits that state change in `onStop`:

```dart
  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    await _player.dispose();
    // the "await" is important
    await AudioServiceBackground.setState(
        processingState: AudioProcessingState.stopped);
    // Shut down this task
    await super.onStop();
  }
```

This way, you can listen for this state in the UI:

```dart
AudioService.playbackStateStream.listen((state) {
  if (state.processingState == AudioProcessingState.stopped)) {
    // take action
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible for > v0.18 to hide the Android Notification? Stop() only seems to stop the track, but does not hide the notification. Or is this an accompanying phenomenon of v0.18 and I have to deal with the always persistent notification?